# Bigquery/ SQL: sequence in same group

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a question in regards to finding the sequence between 2 page types using sql:

Sample data we have:

| SessionID | Page Type |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | account |
| 123 | raw |
| 123 | plp |
| 123 | pdp |
| 123 | account |
| 123 | plp |
| 123 | sample |
| 123 | pdp |
| 123 | plp |
| 123 | pdp |
| 123 | raw |

Ideally output will look like below, only to include records when pdp is clicked right after plp

| SessionID | Page Type |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | plp |
| 123 | pdp |
| 123 | plp |
| 123 | pdp |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to operate based on order  - you must have something to order on
Usually it is timestamp column or position or something else

I assume you have one (in my sample I will use ts column as such)

[image]

Consider below approach to get what you want

```
select * from your_table
qualify (lag(page_type) over win = 'plp' and page_type = 'pdp')
or (lead(page_type) over win = 'pdp' and page_type = 'plp')
window win as (partition by sessionId order by ts)
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Perfect solution thank you so much! And yes I have a page_visit column to define visiting time, thanks for bringing it up.